# How does WWE earn money with an empty audience?

Tags: production, wwe

Due to COVID 19, WWE is hosting their shows with no audience. How does WWE earn money with an empty audience?

Comment: TV show audiences rarely pay for tickets [idk specifically for that show, but that's the general idea] If a show is massively popular the ticket allocation is lottery-style. If a show isn't massively popular, or brand new, they pay people like me to go look enthusiastic ;)  The money is made through the avenues @Jeeped listed &/or advertising revenues.

Answer (score 3):

[BusinessInsider.com](https://www.businessinsider.com/) reported on this in an article back in 2015. The statistics were culled from major North American sports teams.

> The amount of revenue generated by major North American sports team from **the selling of media rights (TV, radio, internet, etc.) is projected to surpass the amount of revenue generated from ticket sales in 2018**, according to a PricewaterhouseCoopers report (via Sports Business Daily). As a result, television ratings have now become the driving force behind sports, even bigger than actually bringing fans to the games.
>   <sub>*source:* [Why TV ratings in sports are more important than attendance](https://www.businessinsider.com/sports-tv-ratings-more-important-than-attendance-2015-11) - Nov 17, 2015</sub>

And again three years later.

> Media rights — or the fees paid to show sports on TV, the internet, and other distribution channels — will remain **the largest and fastest-growing bucket of sports revenues in North America**, according to PwC’s Sports Outlook.
>   <sub>*source:* [Media rights will continue to propel sports revenue](https://www.businessinsider.com/media-rights-propel-sports-revenue-2018-11) - Nov 28, 2018</sub>

Although the WWE should probably be considered a secondary market, they have long embraced home Pay-per-View and licenced satellite broadcast to bars and other public venues for 'championship' events. Cable sports networks broadcast matches of lesser importance on a regular basis and these would be subject to contractual fees as well.

Comment: I hadn't considered WWE would be considered a sport .. honestly ;)

Comment: The WWE calls itself *'sports entertainment'* but there is more than just the question of athletic competition in play there and nothing to do with the question at hand.